# DeviceToken/SystemToken in LookupOrderedRows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobilepush

We have a standard data extension where we store the devicetoken under the column named systemToken. I am trying to use lookuporderedrows function to get another column of the same data extension using the value in the systemtoken column but it is not retrieving any value.

```
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName", 1, "ColumnName desc", "SystemToken", SystemToken)
```

I have also tried `System_Token` and `_SystemToken` but no luck.

For SMS this works:

```
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName", 1, "ColumnName desc", "MobileNumber", MOBILE_NUMBER)
```

I am trying to achieve the same for PUSH using sytemtoken(devicetoken).

Answer (score 1):

Hi @GrzegorzPróchnicki

I found a solution to this:

I used AttributeValue() to get the systemToken

%%[VAR @AttrSys
SET @AttrSys = AttributeValue("SystemToken")
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName", 1, "ColumnName desc", "SystemToken", @AttrSys)]%%

Note: I posted this question but not sure why Stack Exchange is not allowing me to use my existing ID.

Comment: You have probably been banned on that account and likely will be banned on this too. Reach out to support

Comment: Oh, I've seen few times this function, but I didn't think that it could be helpful in such case. Thank you! I will try it in my case as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with the assigning that to a variable, it sometimes helps, as I've found that sometimes it is not possible to pass a value to function from context variable.

Try something like that:

```
VAR @st
SET @st = SystemToken
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName", 1, "ColumnName desc", "SystemToken", @st)
```

---

Additionally, you've mentioned *SMS / Push module*. In that context you do not have loaded regular All Subscribers "data extension", that is why that variable could be empty.

From my personal experience, when I needed to get something from regular Data Extension in SMS, I needed to lookup from `Subscribers` data view contact's subscriber key, then build another lookup to get the value from target data extension.

It seems that only values from those *special* data sets/data extension associated with the used module (Mobile push / Mobile connect) are loaded into the context - so I was starting with only `ContactID`, and dug to data from target Data Extension through two lookups.

---

The example based on my case, used in Mobile Connect SMS message:

```
%%[
VAR @subkey, @subid, @somevariable

SET @subid = contactID
SET @subkey = Lookup("ent._Subscribers", "SubscriberKey", "SubscriberId", @subid)
SET @somevariable=Lookup("SomeDataExtension","WantedColumn","SubscriberKey",@subkey)

]%%

Display %%=v(@somevariable)=%%
```

Comment: Thank you @GrzegorzPróchnicki for the response. I did try assigning it to a variable but no luck. I will try with your second suggested approach. Do you have any such example which you can share here.

Comment: @SudhirKumar I've added my example to answer. I've checked in **Data Designer** that in **Mobile Push** attribute set `ContactID` has the same name.